# How to auto play iframe youtube on webview android

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube

I use android webview in my app for display video from youtube it's work well.

But i want it's auto play.

This is my activity i append **"?autoplay=1"** to videoUrl but nothing change it's still not auto play.

```
public class LandVideoAct extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    String videoURL = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.landfull);
        videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/VYIi49czywo?autoplay=1";
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullwebview);

        String vid = "<html><body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0\"><iframe  width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\""+videoURL+"\" type=\"text/html\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><body><html>";

        WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            }
        };

        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); 
            }
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
            Log.i("GPSNETWORK", "<17");
        } else {
            Log.i("GPSNETWORK", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+">=17");
            mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        }
        mWebView.loadData(vid, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not possible in webview or android browsers. To achieve auto playing, I think you need "YOUTUBE API".

Check below link :

1] [There's no way method to do autoplay video on android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281039/theres-no-way-method-to-do-autoplay-video-on-android-platform)

2] [Youtube Api android autostart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354621/youtube-api-android-autostart)

These above links will give you idea about auto playing as well as youtube api.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946183/android-webview-html5-video-autoplay-not-working-on-android-4-0-3). There are a couple of suggestions that may work for you, however the person who asked that question didn't say if it worked for them or not.

Most of what I'm reading is saying that most mobile platforms block autoplay to avoid poor user experience.

You can try this javascript code below:

```
var myvideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; myvideo.play();
```

For Android 4.2.2+ try adding this in your native code:

```
WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Also check out [this page](https://gist.github.com/aprock/5913322). Which adds the code below to autoplay the video:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
    });
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webview.loadUrl("http://html5demos.com/video");
}
```

Comment: i try to do with your suggestion. But it's still no auto play. Plese see in my question i edit it's with your suggestion. i check my SDK version is 18

Comment: @user2955394 - Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Youtube's restrictions on mobile make it impossible to automatically play audio and video.
So set the User Agent to web view settings:

```
webSettings.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Safari/537.36"
```

There is my all settings about web view:

```
val webSettings = webView.settings
    webSettings.userAgentString = USER_AGENT
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH)
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    webSettings.displayZoomControls = false
    webSettings.builtInZoomControls = true
    webSettings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false)

    webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webSettings.allowFileAccess = true
    webSettings.allowContentAccess = true
    webSettings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true

    webSettings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
    webSettings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)

    webSettings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false

    // Automatic screen
    // Sets whether the WebView should enable support for the "viewport" HTML meta tag or should use a wide viewport
    webSettings.useWideViewPort = true
```

Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. Hope it helps

```
String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
                + "J2fB5XWj6IE?autoplay=1"
                + "&fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
                + "</iframe>\n";
```

From below link

> In Chrome, **autoplay** is also disabled
>
> (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159336)
>
> I believe the same happens with the recent versions of the default
>   Android Web Browser.

Comment: thank you but it's not work for me(not error but still not auto play)

Comment: when i run my app the video show play button and when i click play button it's work well. But i want to auto play it's don't want to click play button.

Answer (score 0):

It's disabled by default based on operating system reason. Chrome disables content by default, too. You can try to code your own app or use Java, Javascript and the YouTube-API instead. Maybe webkit will let you allow to decide what to play based on your battery state in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the trick, I'm using jquery, but it can be done with plain javascript.

```
<iframe id="myvideo" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Vhh_GeBPOhs?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;mute=1amp;enablejsapi=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
  $('#myvideo')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
 }, 250);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Desktop mode on WebView. Youtube will autoplay. Add this:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Safari/537.36")
```

Like this:

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
webView.loadUrl("http://your.web.site/")
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {}
webView.settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON)
webView.settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND)
webView.settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Safari/537.36")
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>16){webView.settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)}
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: String) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A little late but I hope this helps.

After your page is finished loading run this:-

```
 yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button ytp-button')[0].click(); })()");
```