# Auto play video in webview in Amlogic Android Media Boxes

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

I am displaying a youtube link in a webview. I want to autoplay the link.
**Problem is** that, After opening a link i have to click on video then video is playing but i want that video should be play automatically.

Thanks in Advance.

### My Code :

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
      view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
      return true;
    }
}
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyDnYaFtRS0");
```

---

Tested on Devices :
1) Amlogic Android Media Boxes(Android 6.0.1) -> **Not working.**
2) Nexus 5 (Android 6.0) -> **Working.**

Answer (score 1):

Try it

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url{

web.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {

document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");

}

});

Comment: let us know if you have got solution.

Comment: Not found the solution till now.

Comment: Hi have you got the solution of it?

Comment: Not directly by android settings, but using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible in webview or android browsers. To achieve auto playing, I think you need "YOUTUBE API".

Check below link :

1] [There's no way method to do autoplay video on android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281039/theres-no-way-method-to-do-autoplay-video-on-android-platform)

2] [Youtube Api android autostart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354621/youtube-api-android-autostart)

These above links will give you idea about auto playing as well as youtube api.
for more detail you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947758/how-to-auto-play-iframe-youtube-on-webview-android).

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this problem by using javascript to programatically click on videoElement.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {"
              + "var videoElem = document.querySelectorAll('video');"
              + "if (videoElem.length > 0) {"
              + "videoElem[0].click(); return;"
              + "} else {"
              + "console.log('Not Found Video Element..!!');"
              + "}"
              + "})()");
```